# Swapfile issues with vim when using remote Windows 10 SMB Share?

Tags: swap-file

I'm using vim on a Linux machine to write to a Windows 10 share and vim keeps slowing down and giving an error at the status line of `E297: Write error in swap file`.  When I went into the directory to list it I got the following:

```
leeand00@puppetmaster:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=leeand00-pc,share=temp$ ls -la
ls: cannot access '.reorder.py.swp': Invalid argument
total 273
drwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00   4096 Jun 23 07:33 .
dr-x------ 3 leeand00 leeand00      0 Jun 21 09:48 ..
drwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00      0 Jan  3  2017 firmware
-rwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00 199516 Jul  6  2017 IMG_0002.jpg
-rwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00     99 Jun 23 00:21 .~lock.NoHeaders.csv#
-rwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00    208 Jan  2  2017 README.txt
-rwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00    342 Jun 23 07:33 reorder.py
?????????? ? ?        ?             ?            ? .reorder.py.swp
-rwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00  36688 Jun 22 14:23 Headers.csv
-rwx------ 1 leeand00 leeand00  36618 Jun 23 00:21 NoHeaders.csv
```

The swap file looks really strange...is there something else I can do about this?

Comment: Could it be owned by root ? Can you remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:set noswapfile` seems to have taken care of the issue.

Comment: That's not really a solution, though. It's just sweeping the problem under the rug.